# getApplicationContext() on a null object reference on Service that implements RecognitionListener

Tags: java, android, service, speech-recognition, android-context

As a start, I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I still don't seem to find one that has a working answer for my case.

So this is my service class (**EDIT 2:** now almost all the code is here - sorry the variables are in portuguese --> if needed I translate everything):

```
public class Google_voice_recognition extends Service implements RecognitionListener {

    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

    private boolean a_ouvir = false;

    private String processar_fala_string = "";
    private String ultima_fala_processada = "";
    private String fala_processada_total = "";
    private long ativar_resultados_parciais_tempo = 0;
    private int ativar_resultados_parciais_num = 0;
    private boolean ativar_resultados_parciais = true;
    private String ultima_fala_nao_util = "";

    private Context contexto;

    private boolean onEndOfSpeech_ultimo = false;
    private long reposicao_reconhecimento_google_erro_tempo = 0;

    public static final String ACAO_ENVIAR_TAREFA = "enviar_tarefa()";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        contexto = getApplicationContext();
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println("whatever 1");
        if (contexto == null) {
            System.out.println("null 1");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ativar_resultados_parciais = false;//Utils_gerais.func_ext_disponiveis();
        System.out.println(ativar_resultados_parciais);

        System.out.println(this);

        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(contexto);
        Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, contexto.getPackageName());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE, true);
        }
        Reconhecimento_voz_Google listener = new Reconhecimento_voz_Google();
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
        speechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

        processamento_fala_parcial.start();
        reposicao_reconhecimento_google_erro.start();

        System.out.println("whatever 2");
        if (contexto == null) {
            System.out.println("null 2");
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        ultima_fala_processada = "";
        fala_processada_total = "";
        processar_fala_string = "";
        ativar_resultados_parciais_num = 0;
        onEndOfSpeech_ultimo = false;
        ultima_fala_nao_util = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        System.out.println("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG");
        a_ouvir = false;

        onEndOfSpeech_ultimo = true;
        reposicao_reconhecimento_google_erro_tempo = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ativar_resultados_parciais = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
        if (!a_ouvir) {
            return;
        }
        a_ouvir=false;

        onEndOfSpeech_ultimo = false;
        reposicao_reconhecimento_google_erro_tempo = 0;

        System.out.println("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK");
        System.out.println(error);

        ativar_resultados_parciais = false;
        speechRecognizer.stopListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        if (ativar_resultados_parciais) {
            if (matches != null) {

                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.println(matches.get(0).toLowerCase());

                if (!matches.get(0).toLowerCase().equals(ultima_fala_processada) && matches.get(0).toLowerCase().length() - 1 > ativar_resultados_parciais_num) {
                    processar_fala_string = matches.get(0).toLowerCase().substring(ativar_resultados_parciais_num);
                    ativar_resultados_parciais_tempo = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println(processar_fala_string);
                }
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        System.out.println("UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
        a_ouvir=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        onEndOfSpeech_ultimo = false;
        reposicao_reconhecimento_google_erro_tempo = 0;

        a_ouvir=false;
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println(matches);
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        if (matches != null) {
            System.out.println("A------------------------A");
            System.out.println(matches.get(0).toLowerCase().substring(ativar_resultados_parciais_num));
            System.out.println("A------------------------A");
        }

        ativar_resultados_parciais = false;

        if (matches != null) {
            if (matches.get(0).toLowerCase().length() - 1 > ativar_resultados_parciais_num && !matches.get(0).toLowerCase().equals(fala_processada_total)) {
                processar_fala_string = matches.get(0).toLowerCase().substring(ativar_resultados_parciais_num);
                if (!processar_fala_string.equals(ultima_fala_processada)) {

                    System.out.println("whatever 3");
                    if (contexto == null) {
                        //System.out.println(getApplicationContext()); --> "getApplicationContext() on a null object reference"
                        System.out.println(getBaseContext());
                        System.out.println(this);
                        System.out.println("null 3");
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACAO_ENVIAR_TAREFA);
                    intent.putExtra("extras_frase_str", matches.get(0).toLowerCase().substring(ativar_resultados_parciais_num));
                    intent.putExtra("extras_resultados_parciais", false);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(speechRecognizer);
        if (speechRecognizer != null) {
            speechRecognizer.stopListening();
            speechRecognizer.cancel();
            speechRecognizer.destroy();
            speechRecognizer = null;
        }
        Utils_processos.encerrar_pid(Utils_processos.obter_pid_atual());

    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
        if (speechRecognizer != null) {
            speechRecognizer.stopListening();
            speechRecognizer.cancel();
            speechRecognizer.destroy();
            speechRecognizer = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I cut many parts that had nothing to do with the problem and left only what I believe that is connected to the problem (which uses `Context` somewhere).

When I start the service normally as you would (`startService` or `startForeground` - I use the first one since this is on Lollipop), `onCreate()` is called with some context I get from `this` and `onStartCommand()` too, with the same `this` value. That's cool. Now what I don't understand is why `getApplicationContext()` is invoked on some null thing when I call it from `RecognitionListener` methods.

My appologies, as I don't fully understand Android's `Context` stuff, except that it seems to be connected to the process. Speaking of process, maybe it could be useful to say this service is running on a separate process? It is supposed to start the recognition automatically, listen stuff, and tell another running service to execute a function (thus the broadcast). It's on a separate process so I can kill the recognition whenever I want and I don't have to wait until it decides to stop, even after I told it to stop right away. This way it really stops rightaway. But I can't get it to work fully because of that. It stops and stuff, but doesn't return the results. That's useful xD.

The error comes from this method inside `LocalBroadcastManager` class:

```
@NonNull
public static LocalBroadcastManager getInstance(@NonNull Context context) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new LocalBroadcastManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

On the `context.getApplicationContext()` part. That's where the error is. I can pass `context` variable or `this` to `getInstance()`, but the error will come up anyways because `getApplicationContext()` is used, which is the problem here, it seems. I wonder why that happens with `getApplicationContext()` when I call it from `onResults()` - or maybe any other method from RecognitionListener? Is that because it's not from a method that is part of Service? If that's the reason, is there any way of broadcasting a message to the other service? I was trying to avoid things like `SharedPreferences` or files.

By the way, a very weird thing to me: "null 3" appears on the logcat, while none of the others do..... How is that possible?? Why has the variable changed if I didn't tell it to change???

**EDIT 1:** In case it is useful, here is the stacktrace of the error.

```
10-25 18:10:44.080 14968-14968/com.dadi590.androidos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dadi590.androidos:AndroidOS, PID: 14968
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:107)
        at com.dadi590.androidos.Services.Google_voice_recognition.onResults(Reconhecimento_voz_Google.java:232)
        at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$InternalListener$1.handleMessage(SpeechRecognizer.java:467)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:107)
10-25 18:10:44.087 14968-14968/com.dadi590.androidos D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
10-25 18:10:44.142 14968-14968/com.dadi590.androidos I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14968 SIG: 9
```

**EDIT 3:** START_STICKY, START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT don't do anything, if this is useful. Still the exact same error.

Comment: First, `LocalBroadcastManager` has been deprecated for years. Second, it does not work across processes. Third, you do not need `getApplicationContext()`, as `Service` inherits from `Context`, so you can simply use `this`. ""null 3" appears on the logcat" -- that surprises me. From your stack trace, `context` is not `null`, but it is not a valid `Context` instance. For example, the `Service` might have been destroyed by the time `onResults()` is called.

Comment: 1 - I found out it is deprecated minutes ago, but still wanted to understand why this is happening, so I still made the question. 2 - Well, then I'll use the normal broadcaster. Seems I didn't read enough to know it's only in the same process... Thank you. 3 - That I didn't know at all, since that belongs to the part I don't understand about `Context` haha. Still good to know though. 4 - So with destroyed services, methods can still be called... I really have to read more about Android. Thank you again for that. Now, about that, I've no idea why it would be destroyed. Would you know a reason?

Comment: Also, how do you know the context is not null from the stack trace and that is not valid? (sorry if this is an idiot question)

Comment: "how do you know the context is not null from the stack trace and that is not valid?" -- the top "at" line in the stack trace shows where the crash occurred. In your case, that is `android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)`. This means we got to this line of code, then failed there. Your `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance()` line is the next one down. So, `getInstance()` called `getApplicationContext()` on a non-`null` object... but *that* object (a `ContextWrapper`) has a field that was `null`.

Comment: Oh my bad! Sorry!! I'll correct this right now. `this` should be passed there, NOT `context`. That's how it is in the app code. But I made some adjustments to put it here on the question and ended up changing the parameter, but it shouldn't be there. Please look how it is now. I had it with `context` before on the app code. `this` was what made me go that far on the stack trace, because it was failing sooner with `context` there (I tried various ways of obtaining `Context` to see if some would work and `this` was the best one, but still failed).

Comment: OK. That further suggests that your service has been destroyed by the time `onResults()` is called. I have not used `RecognitionListener` or `SpeechRecognizer`. The API looks... lousy. But, it looks like you should not stop your service until you call `stopListening()` on the `SpeechRecognizer`.

Comment: Ok... Then I actually have no idea what's going on here. I don't stop the service anywhere except after calling stopListening(), on which part I kill the PID from inside the service. Though, speechRecognizer is null in the end of onResults(), by the time I try to stop the recognition - I had an IF there because once it appeared there null, and didn't care anymore. Now I checked again and is still null. So by the end of onResults(), speechRecognizer is already null. I'll post more of the code... Maybe it might be of help. Maybe this also further suggests the service has been destroyed? haha

Comment: I've now posted almost all the code of the service. Only missing 2 Threads that do background checks on the speech, but they're a bit big and I didn't include them (I don't think they have anything to do with this, since as a start, one of them is not called on my testings, and the other I've commented the parts that didn't anything, so it's not currently doing anything useful until I get this thing working without it. Hopefully the code will help knowing why it's being destroyed, because I didn't tell it to stop or something. Not here, nor in the other service.